# beginner's c# class question

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtTestPrime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestPrime myNumber = new TestPrime();
            lblAnswer.Text = 
                myNumber.TestPrime(ToInt16(txtTestPrime.Text)) ? "it is prime!" : "it is NOT prime!";
        }

    }
    public class TestPrime(int number)
    {
        bool prime;


    }
```

it doesnt like this line:

```
public class TestPrime(int number)
```

i am getting this error: invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

also getting `expect { and ;` on that line

also on this line:

```
myNumber.TestPrime(ToInt16(txtTestPrime.Text)) ? "it is prime!" : "it is NOT prime!";
```

im getting Error    4   'WindowsFormsApplication1.TestPrime' does not contain a definition for 'TestPrime' and no extension method 'TestPrime' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.TestPrime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

perhaps it is one main thing that i am doing wrong. please help!

Comment: C# is not Scala.  You can't put a parameter list after the class name - instead, you have to write a separate constructor inside the class body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a class and a method on the same line at the same time, that just don't make any sense.

If you want a method to check the number, do the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtTestPrime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this instantiate a new class, which now is not needed
        //TestPrime myNumber = new TestPrime();
        lblAnswer.Text = TestPrime(Int16.Parse(txtTestPrime.Text)) ? "it is prime!" : "it is NOT prime!";
    }

    public bool TestPrime(short number)
    {
        /* your logic */
        /* this method expects a boolean as the return type */
    }
}
```

Some useful links:

- [Introduction to C# Classes](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson07.aspx)
- [C# Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: If `TestPrime` is a method (and I agree it should be), then `new TestPrime()` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, `ToInt16` might mean `Convert.ToInt16`, but `Int16.Parse` would be better yet.

Answer (score 7):

Is `TestPrime` supposed to be a class?  It sounds more like a function (also called "method").

Try changing that line to

```
public static bool TestPrime(int number)
```

Comment: `ToInt16` would still crash and `new TestPrime` would still be crashing as well. The way he calls the method would also crash since you changed to a static method. Provide more info. The change you are offering *will not* solve his problem.

Comment: This is homework.  The best way for the OP to learn is to be given nudges in the right direction, not everything done at once without explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have parameters in a class declaration.

You need to create a constructor taking the desired parameters.

**Example:**

```
public class TestPrime
{
        private bool prime;
        private int _number;
        public TestPrime(int number) 
        {
           this._number = number;
        }
}
```